# How I can connect delphi 2010 to Telegram

Tags: api, delphi, bots, telegram

I'm a Delphi program and I want to connect Delphi 2010 to Telegram.
I found this API https://github.com/ms301/TelegAPI that wont work on D2010

any one have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: Please read about [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [**On topic**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to learn what questions are on topic. In short, you must **describe in details** what problem you have with the code. Click the two links and take your time to read both articles, please.

Comment: This API is for Delphi XE8 and up.

Answer (score 3):

The API you want to use is for Delphi XE8 and up. You can not use it with Delphi 2010. Basically, you need to use a Delphi version supported by the TelegAPI.

Comment: I **guess** that older Delphi versions (not 2010 yet) could support JSON (de)serialization by attributes as well. Of course, it's the author's decision to support only those.

Comment: [Link]http://barnamenevis.org/showthread.php?526969-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D8%A7-API-%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%AA%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%AF%D9%84%D9%81%DB%8C-7&highlight=%D8%AA%D9%84%DA%AF%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85+delphi

Here, I found Telegram On D7 too!

Comment: But in this sample
in component IdHTTP1
it says 2 property missing 

ReadTimeOut
MaxLineAction

Comment: TelegaPi worked with System.Net(introduced in XE8) and XSuperObject(min supported version - XE2)